# What is the return Type signature for an async import of a Vue.js SFC component?

Tags: vue.js, typescript-eslint

When using dynamic imports of Vue Single File Components, what is the return type inside the promise?

```
{
  … components: [ () => import('../components/MyComponent.vue')], …
}
```

typescript-eslint will notify me `Missing return type on function` which I understand and appreciate throughout the project so do not want to turn this warning off.

But what is the type that it returns?

I have used:

```
(): Promise<Vue> => import(…)
(): Promise<VueConstructor<Vue>> => import(…)
(): AsyncComponentPromise<Vue> => import(…)
(): Promise<unknown> => import(…)
```

The last of these is fine during IDE linting but fails at compile time. Each attempt results errors related to missing overloads that I don't understand:

> Type '() => Promise' is not assignable to type 'VueConstructor | FunctionalComponentOptions> | ComponentOptions> | AsyncComponentPromise<...> | AsyncComponentFactory<...>'.
>         Type '() => Promise' is not assignable to type 'AsyncComponentPromise'.
>           Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise | FunctionalComponentOptions, PropsDefinition>> | ComponentOptions<...> | EsModuleComponent>'.
>             Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Promise | FunctionalComponentOptions, PropsDefinition>> | ComponentOptions<...> | EsModuleComponent>'.
>               Type 'Vue' is not assignable to type 'VueConstructor | FunctionalComponentOptions, PropsDefinition>> | ComponentOptions<...> | EsModuleComponent'.
>                 Property 'default' is missing in type 'Vue' but required in type 'EsModuleComponent'.

This is only relevant when using the dynamic/async import methodology, so what is the correct return signature to use?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it should be `(): Promise<EsModuleComponent> => ...`. Does it work? AsyncComponentPromise type refers to the whole function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's the way to go. But I define my route object as a 'RouteConfig' object.

```
import { RouteConfig } from "vue-router";
export default  {
          name: "RouteNameTest",
          path: "test",
          meta: { test: 42 },
          component: () =>
            import(
              /* webpackChunkName: "test-chunk" */ "../views/test.vue"
            ),
        } as routeConfig;
```